# Assign existing ForeignKey to model fields via command line/script using pk or other means

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to import this csv data:

```
1/30/1987,C152,6408H,CXO-CXO,1,0.5,1,,,,,,,,,,0.5,,,,,
4/29/1987,C172,97320,CXO-CXO,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,
12/12/1987,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,
11/12/1988,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,0.6,2,,,,,,,,,,0.6,,,,,
11/17/1988,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,1.1,3,,,,,,,,,,1.1,,,,,
9/9/1989,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,0.8,2,,,,,,,,,,0.8,,,,,
9/11/1989,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,0.7,1,,,,,,,,,,0.7,,,,,
9/18/1989,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,0.8,1,,,,,,,,,,0.8,,,,,
9/28/1989,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,0.7,3,,,,,,,,,,0.7,,,,,
9/29/1989,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,1,3,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,
10/3/1989,C150,10002,CXO-CXO,1,0.6,5,,,,,,,,,,0.6,,,,,
```

Using this script:

```
import os.path
import sys
import csv
import django
import datetime

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "logbook.settings"
django.setup()

from flights.models import Flight, Aircraft, Approach

# converts values, if they exist, to boolean objects
def convertBool(row_id):    
    if row_id:
        row_id = True
    else:
        row_id = False
    return row_id

# assigns row_id as aircraft object
def assignAircraft(row_id):
    aircraft = None
    aircraft_queryset = Aircraft.objects.all()
    if aircraft_queryset.filter(aircraft_type = row_id).exists():
        pass
    else:
        aircraft = Aircraft(
            aircraft_type = row_id,
        )
        aircraft.save()
        aircraft = Aircraft(aircraft.pk)
    return aircraft

# adds N to registration if needed
def editReg(row_id):
    if row_id.startswith('N'):
        pass
    else:
        row_id = 'N' + row_id
    return row_id

#os agnostic file path
userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
path = os.path.join(userhome, 'django_/logbook/', 'logbook.csv')
with open(path, 'r') as logbook:

    reader = csv.reader(logbook)
    next(reader) # skips header

    for row in reader: # iterates rows

        # date to python datetime object
        date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        row[0] = date

        # makes any empty entry default to 0
        for n, i in enumerate(row):
            if i == '':
                row[n]=0

        aircraft = assignAircraft(row[1])

        flight = Flight(
            date = row[0],
            aircraft = aircraft, # how do I make this assign an existing object from Aircraft.aircraft_type!?
            aircraft_ident = editReg(row[2]),
            route = row[3],
            legs = row[4],
            duration = row[5],
            landings_day = int(row[6]),
            landings_night = int(row[7]),
            night = row[8],
            instrument = row[9], 
            # approaches = row[10],
            cross_country = convertBool(row[11]), 
            second_in_command = convertBool(row[12]),
            pilot_in_command = convertBool(row[13]),
            simulated_instrument = row[14],
            instructor = convertBool(row[15]),
            dual = convertBool(row[16]),
            # # remarks = row[17], 
            simulator = convertBool(row[18]),
            solo = convertBool(row[19]),
            # flight_cost = row[20],
            # expenses = row[21],
            )
        flight.save()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvimport.py", line 84, in <module>
    solo = convertBool(row[19]),
  File "/Users/blakepowell/django_/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 537, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Users/blakepowell/django_/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 211, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "9576": "Flight.aircraft" must be a "Aircraft" instance.
```

Currently, assignAircraft() is returning the pk from the newly created instance. I read that it was possible to assign an existing FK to a model using it's pk but haven't figured it out.

This is the solution I'm after:

row[1] will be inserted as an Aircraft instance using its pk (or some other way) into Flight(aircraft = Aircraft.aircraft_type)

Comment: post only the relevent code.  Don't expect anyone to sift through all that to find a bug for you. What' on earth is the point of the assignAircraft methd anyway? Strip out the excess code but add the relevent bits like models

Comment: The main purpose of assignAircraft() is to enter only 1 instance of aircraft since there are hundreds of each throughout the 2100 lines of the CSV.

I'm trying to return the newly created instance for use in flights(aircraft = newInstance)

Comment: that doesn't make it any clearer

Comment: Well, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code doesn't make sense. You just did a creation on an aircraft by doing:

```
# you are creating an aircraft instance here
aircraft = Aircraft(aircraft_type = row_id)
# instance saved to database, all good so far
aircraft.save()
# why don't you return it?
return aircraft
```

Why don't you just return that `aircraft` instance? Why do you create another aircraft instance(not saved):

```
# What are you trying to do here? This is an unsaved aircraft instance
aircraft = Aircraft(aircraft.pk)
return aircraft
```

Comment: I think I found the error. It's only returning an Aircraft.aircraft_type instance when a NEW instance is saved to the Aircraft model. I need each successive occurrence of row[1] to also be passed in 'return aircraft'

Comment: Here's +1 for just trying to make sense of this

Comment: Then you might need to use `get_or_create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create. Be careful of the return type though.